# How do make an array that fits string from stdin?

Tags: c, arrays, newline, fgets

I am trying to use 'gethostbyname'. If I hardcode a host name directly into the function call it works great. However, I am trying to pass user input into this function. I believe my problem may because the array I am passing to the function has many trailing whitespaces.

```
  void connectHost(char *hostname)
    {

    int n;

    //This works
    //n = gethostbyname("irc.ubuntu.com");

    //This always returns NULL
    n = gethostbyname(hostname);

    if(n == NULL)
    {
    printf("Host Not Found.");
    }

    }

    int main()
    {
    char hostname[256];
    fgets(hostname,255,stdin);
    connectHost(hostname);
    }
```

So what is the best way to just pass the host name to the function? Should I not be using fgets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enter `irc.ubuntu.com` as the input, it'll be stored in `hostname` as `irc.ubuntu.com\n`.
You need to remove the `\n` at the end of the string by overwriting it with the nul character as:

```
fgets(hostname,256,stdin);    
hostname[strlen(hostname)-1] = 0;
```

Note that the 2nd argument of [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/) is maximum number of characters to be read (*including* the final null-character), so in your case you pass it `256` not `255`.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you input using `fgets()` remember to exclude the '\n':

```
fgets(hostname,255,stdin);
hostname[strlen(hostname)-1] = 0;
```

Comment: Note that `fgets` does not *always* contain a trailing newline (for example, if the line was truncated or if the last line in a file doesn't end in one).

Comment: @jamesdlin: thanks. i actually provided simple answer that should fit OP's necessity. OP is taking input from `stdin` and having newline problem.

Comment: Using `stdin` makes it very likely that there will be a final newline, but it doesn't guarantee it (you could press the shell's EOF key combination).